# Focus on Bootstrap modal after switching it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a modal which links to another modal. I got it to switch to the other one quite easily with jQuery, but the problem is that after the switch there's a scrollbar for the body of the page even though the loaded modal is very small; It's like the focus is in the page `body` after the modal switch.

This is the code that switches the modals:

```
$('a#login_resend_activation').click(function(){
    $('#login').modal('hide');
    $('#resend').modal('show');
    return false;
});
```

*Note that `a#login_resend_activation` is part of the first modal (the one that's being closed).*

What's possibly happening that the scrollbar is actually being able to scroll my page body (the back of the modal) while the modal is visible? How do I shift the focus to the present modal?

Comment: You realize it's not really a new window, but just an element on the page that looks like a modal, and as such the scrollbar attached to the window is still scrollable ?

Comment: Yes. I had to refer to it somehow though. Anyway, when the first modal is opened up, the body doesn't provide a scrollbar, it's like the modal is becoming the body and its dimensions make up the whole thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `body`s position to `fixed` and overflow hidden:

```
...
$('#resend').modal('show'); 
$('body').css({position: 'fixed', overflow: 'hidden'});
```

**[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cQHhg/6/)** for you I made a while back for someone else.

It's kinda ugly but the point gets across lol

Comment: This is quite some hack, but unfortunately setting my body's position to `fixed` will make it move to the top left (it's centered originally). I'd have to move along with this hack to make it work completely, which would require a lot more of code writing. I'm looking for something that does this a little cleaner. Thanks for your input.

Comment: With my code it will keep the position at the time of fixing and return it as-is when leaving the modal.  Go to the fiddle and pay attention to where you are on the page and then when you click the popup, notice that the background text hasn't moved.

Comment: That was actually the biggest hurdle when I was making that